# getting part of the recv() buffer

Tags: python, sockets, http, websocket, httpserver

I have this code, that print the http server response, but now I'm trying to get the only the status code, and from there make decisions.
like :

Code:200 - print ok
code:404 - print page not found
etc

**PS: cant use http library**

```
from socket import * 

#constants variables
target_host = 'localhost'
target_port = 80
target_dir = 'dashboard/index.html'

# create a socket object 
client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)  # create an INET (IPv4), STREAMing socket (TCP)
 
# connect the client 
client.connect((target_host,target_port))  
 
# send some data 
request = "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:%s\r\n\r\n" % (target_dir, target_host)

#Send data to the socket.
client.send(request.encode())  

# receive some data 
data = b''
while True: #while data
    buffer = client.recv(2048) #recieve a 2048 bytes data from socket
    if not buffer: #no more data, break
        break
    data += buffer #concatenate buffer data

client.close() #close buffer

#display the response
print(data.decode())
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the reception loop as below: extract the first line, split it, interpret the second word as an integer.

```
line = b''
while True:
    c = client.recv(1)
    if not c or c=='\n':
        break
    line += c

status = -1
line = line.split()
if len(line)>=2:
  try:
    status = int(line[1])
  except:
    pass
print(status)
```

If we heavily rely on `try` we can simplify the second part

```
try:
  status = int(line.split()[1])
except:
  status = -1
print(status)
```